# Error on stdr_simulator tutorial

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Using the stdr_simulator tutorial
Using turtlebot for teleoperation

the command:

```
viki@c3po:~/catkin_ws/src/stdr_tele/launch$ roslaunch stdr_tele stdr_keyboard.launch 
receives the message:
[stdr_keyboard.launch] is neither a launch file in package [stdr_tele] nor is [stdr_tele] a launch file name
```

The launch file:

```
<launch>
  <!-- turtlebot_teleop_key already has its own built in velocity smoother -->
  <node pkg="turtlebot_teleop" type="turtlebot_teleop_key" name="turtlebot_teleop_keyboard"  output="screen">
    <param name="scale_linear" value="0.5" type="double"/>
    <param name="scale_angular" value="1.5" type="double"/>
    <remap from="turtlebot_teleop_keyboard/cmd_vel" to="robot0/dmd_vel"/>
  </node>
</launch>
```

What am I doing wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/192147/error-on-stdr_simulator-tutorial/) by [Joseph Landau](https://answers.ros.org/users/5098/joseph-landau/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2014-09-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-09-08**:
do roslaunch in folder  where you have launch file.

**Comment by [Joseph Landau](https://answers.ros.org/users/5098/joseph-landau/) on 2014-09-08**:
That doesn't seem to work.

viki@c3po:~/catkin_ws/src/stdr_tele/launch$ roslaunch stdr_tele stdr_keyboard.launch
[stdr_keyboard.launch] is neither a launch file in package [stdr_tele] nor is [stdr_tele] a launch file name

Also fails when I attempt the roslaunch from the parent folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`roslaunch stdr_keyboard.launch`  is the command

---

Originally posted by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) with karma: 3034 on 2014-09-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0